# tool to graph method calls over time

Tags: java, profiling, dynamic-analysis

I'm looking for a tool that can graph method calls over time for a java app.  Perhaps a profiler or other log parsing tool?

I know I can write something in python and I'll work towards doing this.  I was just hoping not to reinvent the wheel.

edit:

What I ended up doing was writing some python to parse my logs and take snapshots at 5 second intervals. Then I used google docs and a spreadsheet to visualize my data with a chart that had 2 columns of data: time and frequency. Google docs was super useful.  Use the "move chart to own sheet" for a nice fullsize view.   I'll post my python when I clean it up a bit.

here is the output graph from the method I specify in my comment

[image]

Comment: Eclipse profiling can do this but it tends to be a bit of a crux to use.

Comment: Our support guys put together some graphs using RRDTool which has been great.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/screenshots.html). I wouldn't suggesting writing your own tool, this is a space with lots of players already....unless you're really looking for something to do. :-)

Comment: I called JProfiler support and they said they didn't support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

you can also check the NetBeans profiler, that's quite straight forward if you application a standard Java code (I mean, it's a bit more complicated with projects deployed in Glassfish for instance)

[image] *(from Google Image from [Dr. Dobbs](http://i.cmpnet.com/ddj/images/article/2008/0801/080124netbean_f5.jpg))*

**EDIT**: sorry, after another look at your question, it's not exactly what you were looking for, but it might be interesting anyway

Answer (score 1):

[YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/) is probably the most powerful Java profiler out there. It is not free but not unreasonably expensive either. If it doesn't have the feature you are looking for, I kinda doubt any application would.

Answer (score 1):

[VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) is a visual tool integrating several commandline JDK tools and lightweight profiling capabilities. Designed for both production and development time use, it further enhances the capability of monitoring and performance analysis for the Java SE platform.